# How can I group by date alone, when date column is in milliseconds?

Tags: mysql, sql

The date column in the table is in milliseconds, Now I want to group by `DATE` alone excluding the following

```
hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds
```

Comment: Ouch, did my answer not work for you?

Comment: Hey, as I mentioned in the question the date column in DB is in milliseconds. So, converting milliseconds to date is needed. "Group by (FROM_UNIXTIME(Date/1000, '%Y %D %M'))" This helped my need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

convertir la datetime en date puis faire le group :

```
SELECT `updated_at`,FROM_UNIXTIME(`updated_at`,'%Y-%d-%m') daydate FROM `table` GROUP BY FROM_UNIXTIME(`updated_at`,'%Y-%d-%m');
```

Comment: Translation (in case anybody's feeling lazy): `convert the datetime to date then make the group`

Answer (score 5):

Convert the datetime to just a date, and then group:

```
SELECT SUM(foo), DATE(mydate) FROM a_table GROUP BY DATE(a_table.mydate);
```

Comment: Other than by saying explicitly "Convert the datetime to just a date" ?

Comment: Whoops- sorry, missed this. Your answer is good. Also I have got in a mess by deleting the original comment. Not a good day

Comment: If you edit the answer I can undo my foolish downvote.